# Return value previous month for the same combination

Tags: python, dataframe

I tried the below code that i found online but it does not work in my case. I have a dataframe with Dates(MM/YYYYY), Division, Department and finance flag that represents if the department belongs to finance function.Over period of time due to employee transfer from non finance(Fin_Flag No) to finance(Fin_Flag Yes) and Vice versa. so i am trying to add another column that will display finance flag value of previous month. i added Last Month(L_Month) and finance flag (Prev_flag-> my desired output) along with the data below.

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y%m')
df['Desired_output']=df.groupby('GL_FUNC').apply(lambda x :x.Fin_flag .shift()* (x.Date.dt.year*12+x.Date.dt.month).diff().eq(1)).replace(0,"").values
df
```

```
Date GL_FUNC DIVISION DEPARTMENT Fin_flag L_Month Desired_output IamGetting
202108  Q    Q EME    Tech Q EME    Yes    202107   Nan            Nan
202109  Q    Q EME    Tech Q EME    No     202108   Yes
202110  Q    Q EME    Tech Q EME    No     202109   No             Nan
202109  CS   NA       CL NA         No     202108   Yes            Yes
202109  Q    Q Amer   Pr&Ana        No     202108   No             No
202108  CS   NA       CL NA         Yes    202107   nan
202108  Q    Q Amer   Pr&Ana        No     202107   nan
202109  RE   CAS      CAS UNW NA    No     202108   Yes            Nan
202108  RE   CAS      CAS UNW NA    Yes    202107   Nan
```

When i use have duplicate row values

```
Date    GL_Func Division  Department Fin_flag L_Month   Prev_flag   Prior_Flag
202108     Q    Q EME     Tech Q EME Yes      202107    Nan 
202108     Q    Q EME     Tech Q EME No       202107    Nan          Yes
202108     Q    Q EME     Tech Q EME Yes      202107    Nan          No
202108     Q    Q EME     Tech Q EME NO       202107    Nan          Yes
``
```

Comment: Please explain the statement " find out the every movement what was the previous month flag value for that combination(" What is every movement? Given your sample data what is your expected result.  Also, don't post image of your data but include as text formatted as code within your question.

Comment: @itprorh66 I have rephrased my question and Desired output is the column i am expecting

Comment: Any input in the above problem

Comment: Your sample code has nothing to do with your dataframe!  This appears to be some random bit of code pasted into this question to appear to be a MRE.  Where is the real code you are using and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Sorry had to shorten the Column name due to space constraint. "Desired_output" is what was i am expecting and "IamGetting" my current code output is

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your approach as follows:

Given a DataFrame as shown below:

```
df =    Date    GL_Func Division    Department  Fin_Flag  
     0  202108  Q   Q EME   Tech Q EME  Yes  
     1  202109  Q   Q EME   Tech Q EME  No  
     2  202110  Q   Q EME   Tech Q EME  No  
     3  202109  CS  NA  CL NA   No  
     4  202109  Q   Q Amer  Pr&Ana  No  
     5  202108  CS  NA  CL NA   Yes  
     6  202108  Q   Q Amer  Pr&Ana  No  
     7  202109  RE  CAS CAS UNW NA  No  
     8  202108  RE  CAS CAS UNW NA  Yes
```

First sort the df by Department and Date;

```
df.sort_values(by=['Department', 'Date'], inplace=True)
```

Then create the 'Prior_month Flag" as follows:

```
df['Prior_Flag'] = df['Fin_Flag'].shift().mask(df['Department'].shift() != df['Department'])
```

This results in the following df:

```
    Date    GL_Func Division    Department  Fin_Flag    Prior_Flag
8   202108  RE      CAS         CAS UNW NA  Yes         NaN
7   202109  RE      CAS         CAS UNW NA  No          Yes
5   202108  CS      NA          CL NA       Yes         NaN
3   202109  CS      NA          CL NA       No          Yes
6   202108  Q       Q Amer      Pr&Ana      No          NaN
4   202109  Q       Q Amer      Pr&Ana      No          No
0   202108  Q       Q EME       Tech Q EME  Yes         NaN
1   202109  Q       Q EME       Tech Q EME  No          Yes
2   202110  Q   Q EME   Tech Q EME  No  No
​
```

Comment: how to how handle duplicate values rows

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?  What values are duplicated?  What would you like to happen with duplicate rows?

Comment: when i use duplicate value, it is just returning previous row flag value. i have added the output above

Comment: Yes, that is what it is meant to do.  My question would be why do you have duplicate records in the first place?  Can you remove duplicates before performing the operation? Finally if, you can't remove duplicates what would you like to happen?

Comment: My table originally has 250 columns and every row can have different values where in the department can be same. why cant the returned value based on the previous month for that same row combinations.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to ask a new question which clarifies what you want, provides a sample set of data which illustrates your problem, and provides an example of your expected output.